# How to get Ul tag from parent id using prototype?

Tags: prototypejs

```
<div id="menu">
   <ul>
   <li>Menu link</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="content">Dummy content</div>
```

I want to get the UL tag using parent id. 
The condition is if the UL tag is missing, i need to apply new class for the Content Div.

script

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {

        if( --------)
    { 
    $('content').removeClassName('fwidth');

     }
     else{

     $('content').addClassName('fwidth');

     }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your question, but if you want to find out if <div id="content"> has ul elements, try

```
if ($('content').down("ul"))
```